# Full-screen Shoes application?

Tags: ruby, fullscreen, shoes

I looked around the documentation but found nothing - is there a way to make a [Shoes](http://shoooes.net/) app display full screen?

Possibly something like..

```
Shoes.app :fullscreen => true do
  para "test"
end
```

Looking in the source-code, the following lines mentioning "fullscreen" (among others):

```
shoes/app.c:58:  app->fullscreen = FALSE;
shoes/native/cocoa.m:851:  if (app->fullscreen) {
shoes/native/gtk.c:557:  if (app->fullscreen)
shoes/native/cocoa.m:872:shoes_native_app_fullscreen(shoes_app *app, char yn)
shoes/native/windows.c:934:  if (app->fullscreen)
shoes/native/windows.c:935:    style = WINDOW_STYLE_FULLSCREEN;
```

..so it all seems to be there, just doing `:fullscreen => true` seems to have no effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opps, the `app->fullscreen` code quoted in the question was from the latest development code, not the current `2/Raisins` release..

```
$ git co 2/Raisins 
HEAD is now at 42dda8a...  * bugs: closing some bugs, moving others to the next release.
$ grep -r -i fullscreen *
[nothing]
$ git co master 
Switched to branch "master"
$ grep -r -i fullscreen *
shoes/app.c:  app->fullscreen = FALSE;
[...]
```

`:fullscreen` will work in the next version!